Multi belongsToMany in Laravel Eloquent
I'm wondering if there's better way than just the query it self.
I have a structure like this.

characters
character_section
sections
section_user
users

And for characters and sections, they are many to many. Same for sections and users.
That means there are intermediate tables between characters, sections, and sections, users.
What I need is a known chapter, get all the sections and check if this section_user exist. Of course, we know the user_id.
[
    {
        "characer_id": 1,
        ...
        "sections": {
            "section_id": 1,
            ...
            "is_user_existed": 1 //if the section_user existed
        }
    }
]

I tried to add belongsToMany in models. But not sure how to combine them together and check if the section_user record existed.

From what you've said, your database kind of looks like this:
+------------+                                  +----------+                                +---------+
| characters |                                  | sections |                                |  users  |
+------------+ 1                              1 +----------+ 1                            1 +---------+     
|    id (pk) |--+   +--------------------+   +--|  id (pk) |--+   +------------------+   +--| id (pk) |
|        ... |  |   | character_section  |   |  |      ... |  |   |   section_user   |   |  |     ... |   
+------------+  | N +--------------------+   |  +----------+  | N +------------------+   |  +---------+
                +-->| character_id (pfk) | N |                +-->| section_id (pfk) | N |
                    |   section_id (pfk) |<--+                    |    user_id (pfk) |<--+
                    |                ... |                        |              ... |  
                    +--------------------+                        +------------------+

Breaking this down in relationships, this is what we havein terms of relationships for each model:
Character

HasMany CharacterSection (1 to N)
BelongsToMany Section (Many to many or M:N) via the character_section intermediate table (and the CharacterSection pivot model should you have it)

Section

HasMany CharacterSection (1 to N)
BelongsToMany Character (Many to many or M:N) via the character_section intermediate table (and the CharacterSection pivot model should you have it)
HasMany SectionUser (1 to N)
BelongsToMany User (Many to many or M:N) via the section_user intermediate table (and the SectionUser pivot model should you have it)

User

HasMany SectionUser (1 to N)
BelongsToMany Section (Many to many or M:N) via the section_user intermediate table (and the SectionUser pivot model should you have it)

CharacterSection

BelongsTo Character (N to 1)
BelongsTo Section (N to 1)

SectionUser

BelongsTo Section (N to 1)
BelongsTo User (N to 1)

Now, assuming you have the relevant relationships defined in your models, you can make a query to eager load them using with and if your objective is to get a truthy/falsy value in the sections array regarding the existence of that user, you can use withCount with a Closure to count only the users that match a given id.
This will result in a column that either holds 0 (false) or any other number (true).
// assuming we know a character and an user's ids
$character_id = 1;
$user_id = 1;

Character::query()
    ->with([
        'sections' => function ($sections) use ($user_id) {
            $sections->withCount([
                'users AS user_exists' => function ($users) use ($user_id) {
                    $users->where('id', $user_id);
                }
            ]);
        }
    ])
    ->find($character_id);

